# Eclipse Mars: Not showing the new projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I am facing an issue with the Eclipse Mars. Whenever I create a new project in the existing workspace it is not showing in Package Explorer/ Navigator. But it is showing in Project Explorer. When I try to import it, it is not allowing to import since it is already existing in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Well at present i am using eclipse neon, which is latest but i faced same problem in eclipse mars, you are describing and what i did was copy whole project from my project workspace to another local drive. Than removed it from project explorer and deleted it from everywhere. And than again i import and trick worked. Hope this`ll also work in your case.